# Flex items rendering smaller than specified by width / height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a webpage made with flexbox (this part at least). To the right are a few images which appears really small, although it should be way bigger.

Anyone can see what the problem may be ?

Here you can see what it looks like to me:

[image: Here you can see what It looks like to me]

I tried making the image in percentage and trying the padding and margins of the paragraphs, nothing works.

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 63px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

#hoverr:hover {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #464646;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.paragraphs {
  padding: 0 9%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.container img {
  width: 600px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="methods" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Methods</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" alt="Bacn">

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

An initial setting on flex items is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property). This means that items are permitted to shrink as needed to avoid overflowing the container.

You need to disable this feature.

Add this to your code:

```
.container img {
  width: 600px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Or, based on a recommendation in the flexbox spec, use this method:

```
.container img {
  flex: 0 0 600px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
```

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex`
>   shorthand rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the
>   shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate
>   [common uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

```css
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
  line-height: 63px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.smalltext {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.smalltextpub {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

#hoverr:hover {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #464646;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
}

.paragraphs {
  padding: 0 9%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.container img {
  flex: 0 0 600px; /* new */
}

.square {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #769DBD;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="methods" class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
      <span class="smalltext">Methods</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" alt="Bacn">

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="background" class="square"><span class="Capital">B</span>
      <span class="smalltextpub">Background</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem

  </div>
  <img class="imageright" src="http://giscience.zgis.at/gisce/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/300x200.png" />

</div>
```

Comment: +1...I often use the `flex-grow: 1` instead of the shorthand `flex: 1 1 auto`. Does this recommendation mean it is better to use shorthand in general, regardless of which property one want to set?

Comment: @LGSon, since most people don't know, or don't always remember, the initial values of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, the spec recommends always using `flex`, so the author can set all values as desired.

Comment: The spec makes this recommendation FOUR times in this one section alone: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components

Comment: Thanks ... see that now, good they make sure people get it right :)

Comment: You are a life saver!